# Is it possible to run executables/binaries (Already built) as unikernels?

Tags: unikernel

TIA. Is it possible to run Linux binaries like chrome without building from source as unikernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSv unikernel (http://osv.io) is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to run arbitrary linux ELFs as unikernels via tools such as https://ops.city && using the Nanos unikernel https://github.com/nanovms/nanos .

However, chrome itself would not be supported currently as that is a gui program and at least for Nanos programs they are server-side only.